# How to set custom image for link shorcut created by drag on desktop using HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dragging Link</title>
        <script>
            function drag(event) {
                var dt = event.dataTransfer;
                dt.setData("text/uri-list", "http://www.mozilla.org");
                dt.setData("text/plain", "http://www.mozilla.org");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Click Me</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have an anchor tag in my html page.

When I drag that link outside the browser to my desktop a shortcut is created.

Icon image for that shortcut is set to the favicon image of default browser of the system.

I want to set the icon image for the shortcut using html and javascript.

Comment: show us the drag code where shortcut is created

Comment: +1 @doniyor :) nice nice ;)

Comment: Might this help? - http://kenneth.io/blog/2010/05/04/desktop-icons-in-google-chrome/